# Managed ESENT: Open dictionary as readonly for accessing from multiple processes

Tags: c#, .net, esent

How can I open a persistent dictionary in readonly mode, so that multiple processes can read data from it simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can't.

If you are interested in making the changes, you'd need to change PersistentDictionary.CheckDatabaseMetaData()'s call to Api.JetAttachDatabase() and Api.JetOpenDatabase(). You'd have to change the grbits being passed to those functions.

Unfortunately if you do make the fix, I don't think your code can be shared for the rest of the community. MS's policy used to be that we can't accept source-code contributions from outside. I have heard that it may no longer be true, but I would need to confirm it.

How important is it?

-martin

Comment: Lack of this feature certainly makes it more difficult to leverage ESENT for caching during SHFB builds if you also want to run your builds in parallel.